# Unable to get user input from a form in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a form which renders, but when I click the submit button, I am not exactly sure how to get the results.

Here is my Activity class:

```
package com.problemio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddProblemActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_problem);


        final EditText problemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problem_name);  
        String name = problemName.getText().toString();  

        final EditText problemText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problem_text);  
        String text = problemText.getText().toString();          

   System.out.println(name);     
   System.out.println(text);        




//        Button browseProblemsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.browseProblemsButton);   
//        Button searchProblemsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchProblemsButton);   
 //       Button myProblemsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myProblemsButton);           


    }

    public void sendFeedback(View button) 
    {  


        System.out.println("3");
        Button addProblemButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send_feedback);   

        addProblemButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
               System.out.println("4");

              //Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProblemioActivity.this, AddProblem.class);
              //ProblemioActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });         
        System.out.println("end");

        // Do click handling here  
    }      
}
```

I put some System.out statements in there to see if anything gets written to my log output, but that didn't work. I am new to Android dev - is there a commonly used way to output things to the console?

I am also not sure where and how to get the input from the form elements.

Help appreciated,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you get what even the user has input. You actually had all the code you needed in the first place, just not placed correctly. Your listener should look like this and be placed in the `onCreate()` method (if I'm understanding your intentions correctly):

```
Button addProblemButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send_feedback);
addProblemButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{  
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
      String name = problemName.getText().toString();
      String text = problemText.getText().toString(); 
      sendFeedback(name, text);
    }
});
```

Then your sendFeedback function would look like:

```
private void sendFeedback(String name, String text){
   //Do what ever you need to here for sending feed back.
}
```

As @onit mentioned, you should use the [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class to print out debug information. Specifically [Log.d()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29).

Comment: and this listener should be inside the sendFeedback() method or the onCreate() method? Thanks!

Comment: thanks, that is great! I just accepted the answer. If I can ask, one more Q: What if I need to display error messages to the screen, or insert that data to a remote database, what are the good practice procedures for that?

Comment: @Genadinik That's a little more involved. I'd need more space than I have in these comments to address those extra questions. You should just post them as a separate question here on stackoverflow (but do some basic research first i.e. google).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using System.out. By default, System.out outputs to /dev/null so there is no output. You can redirect System.out using the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html), to print the data to your log. You can also post information to your Log using the [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class.